# Sharepoint link to sub folders from Top says Sorry, something went wrong

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Web part is allocated on top of sharepoint 2013 and it contains multiple sub folders.
I can open the folders through parent folder but direct link to  doesn't work properly.
I checked other browsers, other PCs, other AD accounts but got the same result.
I deleted the web part and remade again, it didn't work.

Maybe it's a simple problem but does anyone have ideas?

Thanks,